# Play framework isn't working because of missing dependencies

Tags: java, playframework, frameworks, dependencies, sbt

So I am trying to run my Play! framework web app, and I am having difficulties.
I am running on an **OFFLINE** ubuntu machine.
I created the web app project using the activator, and now I am running it like that:

```
# ./activator run
```

I am getting an UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES error:

```
unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.5
```

I installed sbt deb package on my system and it's still doing that!
How can I fix it?

Comment: You say offline - it probably cannot download a (Java) dependency from an online Maven repository then.

Comment: You should give us the code of your build.sbt. Anyway Gimby is probably right, play can't download dependencies.